# console.log doesn't work when there's an error later in the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, console.log

I'm trying to debug some code in Express.js using console.log statements. However, it seems as long as there's an error in the function, even if the error occurs later than the console.log statement, none of the console.log statements execute. Why is this?

I've commented out the function, line by line, and found that the console.log statements work if one of the later lines are commented out, but nothing is printed out if it is not. If console.log isn't blocking, console.warn and console.error don't work either.

```
async delete(id) {
    console.error("repo");
    let color = await this.get(id);
    console.warn(color);
    let event = await this.events.create("Delete Color", 1,
      this.name, color.name);
    const color = await this._delete({ where: { id }}, true,
      { eventId: event.id }); // this is where the error occurs
    await this.events.done(event.id);
    return color;
  }
```

I expect console.log, or at least console.warn and console.error to be blocking, such that they should execute in order. Since the line containing `this._delete()` occurs later than the console.error and console.warn statements, it should print those out in the console regardless of whether the function works. But it does not.

Comment: Re-declaring `const color` causes a compile error before attempt to execute the function. Is that the error you are referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As charlietfl commented, the function as a whole is incorrect due to the variable **color** already being declared.

The error is not a runtime error but a SyntaxError, preventing the function from executing at all.